# How can I replace the search results displayed by Wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development, search

I'm working on a plug-in which will override the search results returned by Wordpress, with results from a custom XML feed. However, I'm not looking to do this on a separate page, but to  replace the results Wordpress would normally display on the blogs search page with the results from my XML feed.

I have been unable to find a filter or hook which would allow me to intercept or override the results wordpress returns, nor can I find one which allows me to override what is displayed on the page. My first thought was to look for something similar to [the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content), but I'm unable to locate anything similar to that for use in this situation.

The plug-in is going to be used by sales staff, so  the plug-in needs to work in such a way that it requires as little work and technical knowledge as possible on the part of installer. My reasoning for wanting to override the results instead of inserting a new widget is that I want the plug-in to use the same search form the theme uses by default.

Is this even possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: To be clear. Will you return results from outside of Wordpress? Or just change the search result format to a custom XML feed?

Comment: Why would you over-ride the search results instead of just providing an alternative and disabling the default search.

Comment: @Steven The results will be coming from outside Wordpress and replaced with results from an XML feed. The plug-in is only meant to be used by the company I'm developing the plug-in for,and they simply want to populate it with their own search results.

Comment: @wyck It's going to be used by sales staff so it needs to be as easy to install as possible, without any manual work required. On the same note I would like for it just use the same search form the theme uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use template_include filter hook to check if the current call is a search call and if so include your own template in which you can do what ever you want :

```
add_filter('template_include','my_custom_search_template');

function my_custom_search_template($template){
    global $wp_query;
    if (!$wp_query->is_search)
        return $template

    return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/my_search_template.php';

}
```

Comment: My concern with this is that the plug-in needs to be dropped into any WordPress theme without creating a new template page. I came across this method myself and I believe it would require me to create a template page for the results, or choose a fitting template page. As noted above, the plug-in is going to be used by sales staff so that's not an ideal option.

Comment: In that case take a look at `the_posts` filter hook where you can run the same check if the current query is a search query and if so return your results.

Comment: I'll take a look at that and report back, thank you :)

Comment: The Posts was a good idea, but due to the theme I'm working for with it's not the ideal solution. However I ended up using a slightly different solution then expected, and I template_include was a key component in that.

Comment: Are you able to share the solution that you came up with?

Comment: @MadtownLems If I still had access to the code, I would. I'm not sure why I didn't think to share my solution to begin with, and it's been so long now I can't remember exactly what I did.